# Best way to do a update every minute

Tags: android

i need to make an update every minute by checking a xml to know if i need to update or not.

I hesitate between some way because i haven't proprely understood service on android

I can do an alarm who launch a activity every minute my activity need to be a reicever or a service?

Can i launch a service every minute without an alarm?

Or need i to make a loop in my service who launch a function every minute?

And can i (if i use alarm and launche many time same activity/service) keep a variable to know if i need to update i mean if i need to dll big file during update it can be longer than 1 minute and i don't wan't to launch multiple update at the same time so i need to use a boolean to know if an update is active or not.

Comment: register a broadcast receiver on the TIME_TICK broadcast. it happens every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't fight for answer me :P

What i found.
I have made an Update class who extend Service one Update execution Make all update and quit the Service the service do not run in background all time
And i join it to a Alarm manager who launche it every 60s
My code look like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),Update.class.getCanonicalName());
i.setComponent(comp);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager amgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
amgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),60000, pending);
```

I still don't know if it's the best way or the GOOD way to do it but it's work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea. Me too I was looking for similar solution. Another one is to register a Broadcast recevier to time tick and update the app only to certains hours (see [How to update an app widget on midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751536/how-to-update-an-app-widget-on-midnight)) but I think that your solution is best in term of saving CPU resources. Don't register a BR for ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, it restarts your Update service.